# Find a Match between Two Columns by Referring to a List

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two columns (column A and column B) which has a list of companies.

Between that list of companies in column A and B, there were companies which are called 'global companies'.

I also have a list of that 'global companies' which I put it in a column (Column E). It can be put at other place as well, no problem.

How to make excel can identify between column A and column B which one is a 'global company' (by referring to column E or somewhere I put the list) and put the name of that 'global company' in column C (a new column)?

Comment: anyone can help me? Do I need to use something like vlookup or macro perhaps?

Comment: BIG question, what if BOTH the companies in column A and B are in the global companies list, what then would you put in column C?

Comment: @user1676434 - This is **easily** done with a formula, we just need a bit more data...

Comment: @t.thielemans nope, because column A is company who act as a seller and column B is company who act as a customer

Comment: @JohnBustos if both companies in column A and B are in the global companies list, both of the companies will be in column C. is it possible?

Comment: Yes - I'll give you a solution in a short while...

Comment: @JohnBustos the example is like this: "Matrix" is a company in column A, "DEFG" is a company in column B. By referring to the list of 'global companies', "Matrix" is listed as a 'global company'. So, in Column C, it will appear "Matrix".

Comment: @JohnBustos the other problem that I faced is the name of the company is not consistent. For example, company "Jane and Frank", there are also written as "Jane & Frank" in the list, but it is the same company. Another example is "H Tech Japan" but there is also "H Tech UK" but it is the same company.

Comment: that is a COMPLETELY different question regarding how you want to decide if a name is *similar enough* to what you have in a list... I would recommend you come up with specific criteria as to how you decide if a name is close enough and ask that question separately.

Comment: @JohnBustos I'm sorry, I forgot to tell the criteria in detail. I'll ask a new question. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your criteria, if you name your global companies list `GlobalCompanies`, then paste this formula in C1 and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,GlobalCompanies,1,0) & " ","")&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,GlobalCompanies,1,0),"")
```