# Find a Match between Two Columns by Referring to a List and put the result in a new column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vlookup

I have two columns (column P and column Q) which has a list of companies.

Within that list of companies in column P and Q, there were companies which are called 'global companies'.

I also have a list of that 'global companies' which I got it via email (not in excel format). In that email, there are about 85 companies listed.

The company name in the 'global companies' list and also in column P and column Q were not consistent. For example, there are company written as "Jane **and** Frank" and the same company written as "Jane **&** Frank". Another example is "H Tech Japan" and there is also "H Tech UK", but it is the same company.

How to make excel can identify between column P and column Q which one is a 'global company' (by referring to where I put the 'global companies' list; perhaps in a column of the same sheet or somewhere else)  and put the result of that 'global company' in column R (a new column beside column Q)?

Comment: For example, in column P: "Jane and Frank" or "Jane & Frank", in column Q: "H tech Japan" or "H Tech UK", according to the 'global companies' list, "Jane and Frank" were in the 'global companies' list. So, in a new column (column R) will appear "Jane and Frank" as the result. And let say if both companies is in 'global companies' list, so in column R will appear both companies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a Match between Two Columns by Referring to a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362665/find-a-match-between-two-columns-by-referring-to-a-list)

Comment: @TimWilliams I provide a more detail of criteria in this second post. Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Some of those variant names look totally different.  There's no easy way to clean them up other than manually, though you could maybe perform some half-way cleanup via code if there were some repeatable patterns which could be coded.  However there's not enough data in your question to make any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but not an easy one....

1) First of all, copy and paste all contents of columns P and Q in a new sheet, one under another, so it becomes a single column with company names.

2) On the ribbon Data, select Remove Duplicates, then OK.

3) Sort the column in alphabetical order. From here, you have two options:

3a) If your list has a manageable size, you can manually do the task. The idea is to copy this column, say A, onto column B, and manually fix the names so they match a pattern (in this case, your 85-item list). You will have something like:

```
  A                   B
H Tech Japan      H Tech Japan
H Tech Japón      H Tech Japan
H Tech UK         H Tech Japan
H Tech jp         H Tech Japan
Jane & Frank      Jane & Frank
Jane et Frank     Jane & Frank
Jane and Frank    Jane & Frank
Jane y frank      Jane & Frank
Jane & FRaNK      Jane & Frank
```

3B) Now, if the list size is unmanageable to do something by hand, you can automate the process to a reasonable extent (I'd say 70% or more of the matches are accurate) using an Excel add-in called Fuzzy Lookup; you can download it on Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

It does pretty much the same thing: using a fuzzy algorith, it matches patterns of similar text sequences, and return a column of matches. There are lots of YouTube videos explaining how to use the Fuzzy Lookup for Excel, and the time you "waste" learning it is totally worth.

Note that, even using this program, It's always a best practice to check the matches and manually correct not found items or mismatches, even if there are few of them.

4) By one way or another, you should now have a column with inputs from the original columns P and Q (column A from the new Sheet), and the correct counterparts next to it (column B). Now, back to the original table:

- Open a new column next to P
- Use a Vlookup to search the values on P on the corrected list [=VLOOKUP(P2;[the list range];2;0)]
- Double-click the small black mark on the inferior right part of cell Q2, to expand the formula until the last item of the column.
- The formula range should be selected now. If not, select it (say, Q2 to Q[last row]), copy with CTRL + C, paste as a value with ALT + C V V. Select the range again, CUT it and PASTE in cell P2 (replacing the old values).

Do the same process for column Q.

5) Having the 85-items list in another sheet, create two new columns (say, IsGlobal_P and IsGlobal_Q) and paste the following formula to return "Yes" if it's global, and "No" if it's not:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(P2;Sheet2!$A$1:$B$300;0));"No";"Yes") (for variable IsGlobal_P)

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Q2;Sheet2!$A$1:$B$300;0));"No";"Yes") (for variable IsGlobal_Q)
```

Now you have the Global companies identified!

Hope it helps...